# How to install additional python libraries such as "bs4" or "Tensorflow" for SublimeText "virtualenv" package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, virtualenv, sublime-text-plugin

I use SublimeText for programming in python - it's easy and to build a program I have to just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. To use additional libraries such as "requests" or "tensorflow" I've installed "VirtualEnv" package for SublimeText https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Virtualenv. I tried to use source /... my path.../activate, but instead of activation there is different python versions

```
suleyman@Linuxoid:~/.virtualenvs/bin$ ls
python  python3  python3.6
```

And i can't use `pip install bs4` (for example) to install additional python's libraries. So, how to install python's libraries in SublimeText's "virtual environment" package? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SublimeText itself doesn't install Python packages. Instead, the virtualenv package substitutes a Python binary that you specify instead of the system installation whenever you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Your virtual environments are stored in the `~/.virtualenvs` directory (though you can keep them anywhere). From your snippet above, it appears you have three virtualenvs installed, called `python`, `python3` and `python3.6`.

To install `TensorFlow` or `Requests`, you need to activate your virtualenv from the terminal:

```
source ~/.virtualenvs/python3.6/bin/activate
```

Then run your installation commands:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

You can verify the installation completed successfully by running `pip freeze`.

In sublime, check the virtualenv package settings to confirm that it's pointed at your `~/.virtualenvs` directory. When you run the command to select a virtualenv (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), you will see a list of all the virtualenvs saved to that folder. If you select the `python3.6` environment, you can now use Tensorflow.

Comment: suleyman@Linuxoid:~/.virtualenvs$ cd bin
suleyman@Linuxoid:~/.virtualenvs/bin$ ls
python  python3  python3.6
suleyman@Linuxoid:~/.virtualenvs/bin$ source python3/bin/activate
bash: python3/bin/activate: Not a directory
suleyman@Linuxoid:~/.virtualenvs/bin$

Comment: python3.6 is not a directory

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any virtualenvs created yet. Navigate to your ~/.virtualenvs folder and create a new virtualenv by running: virtualenv <insert name here>. This will create a new directoy containing a complete Python installation. Then run source <virtualenv name>/bin/activate and proceed as outlined above.

Comment: Thank you. There is also one thing that I missed, from SublineText I have to activate it by selecting Ctrl+Shift+P -> virtualenv: Activate option. Than you.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I have edited my response to include the key shortcut. Will you please mark this answer as accepted? Thank you!